# Sed or Wk formatting several lies columns and set into variables

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, awk, sed

Below you find output of my command that I use to extract 2 lines  from a text file. I have to assign the host-names and port-names to 4 distinct global variables so I can use these to do further inquires in other part of the script.

```
cat file1 | grep -A7 SECTIONA  | grep -E 'Address|BackupAddress
```

produces two lines below

```
Address host1  port_1  Address
BackupAddress host2 port_2  BackupAddress
```

I need assign host and port columns to distinct global variable ( not print) 
to use later in the script.

```
hosta="host1"
porta="port_1"
hostb="host2"
portb="port_2"
```

Please assist?

Comment: Add file1 to your question.

Comment: Btw: `Address` is a substring of `BackupAddress`.

Answer (score 1):

```
source <(sed -n 's/^Address *\([^ ]\+\) *\([^ ]\+\).*/hosta="\1"\nporta="\2"/p;
        s/^BackupAddress *\([^ ]\+\) *\([^ ]\+\).*/hostb="\1"\nportb="\2"/p' file1)
```

Comment: Hi Michael - Thx for reply . this solution prints the desired output, however, when I echo the variables or try to use them, they are blank. It seems all the command does is to print the output. How can we turn this output to global  variables? A read command? Not sure?

Comment: I have amended my answer.